# How to get char[] to work with std::map

Tags: c++, arrays, stl, dictionary

EDIT after answered:

`<` should be provided for `std::map`. For more information about **best practice, go for James McNellis's answer**.

The code included in this question is poorly written. It is just because I am playing with SPOJ and the input data is strictly valid. The `std::string` approach is what I chose at first, but it turned out to be not fast enough.

Thank you.

---

I know I cannot use `char[]` directly with map, such as `map<char[], int>`. Thus I put it in a class. But it still can go through compilation. How to deal with that?

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

class id {
public:
    char v [30];
};

int main () {
    map<id, int> m;
    id a;
    while (gets(a.v)) {
        m[a]++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

```
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.3.4/include/g++-v4/bits/stl_function.h: In member function ‘bool std::less<_Tp>::operator()(const _Tp&, const _Tp&) const [with _Tp = id]’:
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.3.4/include/g++-v4/bits/stl_map.h:418:   instantiated from ‘_Tp& std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::operator[](const _Key&) [with _Key = id, _Tp = int, _Compare = std::less<id>, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const id, int> >]’
prog.cpp:15:   instantiated from here
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.3.4/include/g++-v4/bits/stl_function.h:230: error: no match for ‘operator<’ in ‘__x < __y’
```

It seems it has something to do with comparison, but I am still in the dark.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to implement the `<` operator

```
class id {
public:
    char v [30];
    bool operator<(const id &rhs) const{
        return strcmp(v,rhs.v) < 0;
    }
};
```

EDIT: As a side note your code is a very poor way of doing things.  See some of the answers for an explanation why.

Comment: You answer is exactly what I want. Thank you very much. (Issues about the code is explained in the question edit. I hope it was the best way Stack Overflow worked.  By the way, my answer has finally been accepted.)

Answer (score 6):

First things first:  never, ever use `gets`.  It cannot be used safely and any program that uses it has a security vulnerability.  There is no way to limit the number of characters that `gets` can write to the buffer that you provide it, so there is no way to prevent a buffer overflow.  If you do need to use the C I/O library, you should use `fgets` instead, which allows you to specify the maximum number of characters to be read.

The reason that you are seeing this error is that the key type that you use must be comparable somehow.  By default `std::map` uses `operator<`, which you do not define for `id`, hence the compilation error.  You either need to define `operator<` to compare two `id` objects or you need to write a comparator functor that can be used to compare the two objects.  Regardless which you choose, the comparator must provide a [strict-weak ordering](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/StrictWeakOrdering.html).

Since you are programming in C++, the ideal solution here is to use idiomatic C++:

```
std::map<std::string, int> m;
std::string s;
while (std::cin >> s) {
    m[s]++;
}
```

`std::string` already provides `operator<` that provides a lexicographic ordering, so you don't need to define a comparator yourself.

Comment: No; `fgets` is part of the C Standard Library and thus takes a `FILE*`, like `stdin`.

Comment: I know your approach is the best practice, and it was my first try, long before I asked this question. But it keeps getting "time limit exceed". Thank you very much. (Now my answer gets accepted with dangerous `gets`....)

Answer (score 0):

In order to insert into the map, the map needs to be able to compare id's.  You haven't provided an implementation of operator< that it can use.  You have two options:

1. Provide one, example given by another answer here.
2. Use std::string instead.

I think you should use std::string.  You can use the .c_str() method to convert it to a char array when you need to.