# size_t: an operator? (and a way to use unordered_set)

Tags: c++, c++11, operators, unordered-set

What is

```
operator size_t () const
```

Environment: Visual Studio 2010 Professional

---

**TL; DR**

Today I was searching for a way to use `std::tr1::unordered_set`. Because I asked for [how to use `std::map`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6210182/how-to-get-char-to-work-with-stdmap) last time, I decided to find it out myself.

I googled and most of the results told me to have a struct to do hashing. The way looked a little bit complicated for me, and I kept searching and finally came across another approach.

I need to implement

```
bool operator == (const edge & another) const
```

and

```
operator size_t () const
```

The resulting code is near the end of the question.

`==` is familiar without any problem. [`size_t`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Size_t) is familiar, too. But **what is `operator size_t`**?

It seems like `equals` and `hashCode` for Java, which need to be overridden together according to Effective Java. But I am not sure, especially when the name is `size_t`.

---

The resulting code is as follows. The complete program works fine, and produces correct outputs.

```
class edge {
public:
    int x;
    int y;
    edge(int _x, int _y) : x(_x), y(_y) {
    }
    bool operator == (const edge & another) const {
        return (x == another.x && y == another.y);
    }
    operator size_t () const {
        return x * 31 + y;
    }
};
```

---

A little bit more:

Not

```
size_t operator () const
```

which cannot be compiled:

```
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'const'
error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
error C2059: syntax error : '{'
error C2334: unexpected token(s) preceding '{'; skipping apparent function body
```

Even not

```
int operator size_t () const
```

but as I see it, the function returns `int`. The error code is as follows:

```
error C2549: user-defined conversion cannot specify a return type
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's the [type cast operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ts48df3y.aspx). Basically provides for implicitly converting the object to the specified type, in this case `size_t`.

**EDIT:**

Say you have a function defined as follows:

```
void Foo( size_t x )
{
  // do something with x
}
```

If your class `edge` defines the type-cast operator for conversion to `size_t` you can do the following:

```
edge e;
Foo( e );
```

The compiler will automatically convert the `edge` object to `size_t`. As @litb says in the comments section, do not do this. Implicit conversions can cause trouble by allowing the compiler to perform conversions when you may not have intended for that to happen.

You should instead define a member function like `edge::to_size_t()` (I know that's a terrible name) to perform the conversion.

As an example, `std::string` defines the `std::string::c_str()` member function instead of defining the type-cast operator for conversion to `const char *`.

**EDIT 2:**
Sorry, I didn't read your question carefully enough. Now I see you're trying to use your class in an `std::unordered_set`. In that case you should define functors that do the hash and compare operations for your class. Alternatively, you can provide template specializations of `std::hash` and `std::equal_to` for your class and not have to specify the optional template parameters when creating the `unordered_set` object.

As you've asked in the question, this is very much like Java's `hashCode()` member function, but since C++ classes do not all derive from a common base class like Java classes, it is not implemented as an override-able base class function.

Comment: Would you please provide more details about how this _implicit conversion_ works? And why does it need to be converted to `size_t`?

Comment: @Dante is not a Geek: I've added more details.

Comment: I change `operator size_t () const` to `size_t to_size_t() const`, but it does not work. Your added details mean _in general_, I should not write this kind of conversion, right? In `std::tr1::unordered_set`, it seems to require that, and here is why I asked why. It works as hashing as it is converted to an unsigned integer (which is `size_t`)?

Comment: @Dante is not a Geek: Yes, you're absolutely correct; I've edited the answer again :-). In general, it is a bad idea, but required in this case.

Comment: Sorry but the last bit (maybe...): the normal way to include a hash function is to define that _outside_ the class itself?

Comment: @Dante is not a Geek: Yes, you can define it as functors outside the class itself. Here's an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099540/defining-custom-hash-function-and-equality-function-for-unordered-map. Another way to do this is to provide template specializations for `std::hash()` and `std::equal_to` for your class type.

Comment: @Praetorian: Are you sure that a conversion-to-size_t is automatically used by `std::hash<T>`? I just tried that and it didn't work. As far as I know, you have to specialize `std::hash<T>` manually, no way around that -- there's no "I'm the hash function" member.

Comment: @Kerrek SB: I could be wrong, but what if you specify the type-cast operator and then pass in your class as the optional hash function template parameter to `unordered_map`?

Comment: @Pretorian: How is that supposed to work, `unordered_set<Foo, Foo>`? The hash class has to be a "callable type", and the cast operator does *not* provide this behaviour.

Comment: @Kerrek SB: You're right, the type-cast operator overloading doesn't work. But you can define a function call operator that takes a const reference to your object and then use your class type for the hash function. Do the same for the compare operation as well and you can use `unordered_set< Foo, Foo, Foo >`

Comment: @Pratorian: OK -- you **could** do that, but you'd get a badge for most counter-intuitive design! (And what if those operators are already taken?) The main beef with that is that you need to remember this when you write your container parameters, which is why I'd usually prefer specializing `std::hash`. Almost always, even, there's really never a need to have more than one hash function for a type...

Comment: @Kerrek SB: I agree, that would be a counter-intuitive design (I even upvoted your comment myself :-)). Anyway, I've edited the answer.

Answer (score 2):

It is a conversion operator, as hinted by `error C2549: user-defined conversion cannot specify a return type`. It defines how your type can be converted into `size_t` in this case. In general, `operator X() {...}` specifies how to create a `X` from your type.

Comment: Would you please provide more details about how this conversion works? And why does it need to be converted to `size_t`?

Answer (score 2):

What is `operator size_t () const`?

It's a [conversion-function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5s5sk305%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). It's a function that allows you to ***implicitly*** convert an object of your class to type `size_t`. See further info and examples in the link I provided. Hth.

Comment: Would you please provide more details about how this _implicit conversion_ works? And why does it need to be converted to `size_t`?

Comment: @Dante is not a Greek: I believe the link I provided contains multiple examples and a good explanation. No?

Comment: the link does not answer the second part of the question.

Comment: @Dante: We don't have enough information to tell for sure, but it sounds like the dubious-sounding approach to using `unordered_set` that you googled requires that the objects use this conversion operator to provide their hash-code. This is quite dangerous, since it stops the compiler from catching errors such as typing `int x = edge;` when you meant `int x = edge.x;`. With the conversion operator, this will assign the edge's hash to `x`. As you say in the question, the usual approach is to define a functor to calculate the hash.

Comment: @Mike Seymour, and the functor has to be defined somewhere outside the class?

Comment: @Dante: There must just be a member function called `GetHash()`

Comment: @Dante: I'd define it outside the class, but you could nest it inside if you prefer. Then you need to specify it when declaring your set type: `unordered_set<edge, edge_hash>`. Alternatively, you could perhaps define it as a specialisation of `std::tr1::hash`, then you won't need to specify it as an argument to `unordered_set`.

Answer (score 1):

In any class `Foo`, `operator T () const` is a **cast operator** which lets you cast `Foo` to `T`:

```
Foo x;
T y = x; // invokes Foo::operator T() const
```

For example, an `std::fstream` has a cast-to-bool operator so you can use it in expressions like `if (mystream) ...`.

---

In response to your need to use unordered containers: You will need to implement a hash function or function object, which matches the signature `size_t (const Foo &)`. If you want to do it with least visible impact on the user code, specialize `std::hash<Foo>`:

```
size_t my_magic_hash(const Foo &); // defined somehow
namespace std {
  template <>
  struct hash<Foo> : public std::unary_function<const Foo &, std::size_t>
  {
    inline std::size_t operator()(const Foo & x) const
    {
      return my_magic_hash(x);
    }
  };
}
```

Now we can use `std::unordered_set<Foo>` directly, provided `Foo` provides `operator==`.

Comment: Note that the above also works if there is a `T::T(const Foo&)` defined.

Comment: @Node: Yes, either you convert A to B, or you construct B from A. What happens if both are defined, though, does the one-argument constructor take precedence?

Comment: Why does it need to be converted to `size_t`?

Comment: @Dante: What do you mean? I'm answering two questions, 1) what is a cast operator, and 2) how to specify a hash function. The two are different things. The hash function is just an ordinary function (or functor), not cast operators are used there.

Comment: @Kerrek SB, I know, my _why_ is for the reason `size_t` acts as hashing.

Comment: @Dante: a type doesn't really "act" at all -- it's just a convenient, universal, unsigned integral type of machine-convenient size! What better type would there be for a hash value? You want it to be fast and big, so this is exactly the right type.

Comment: @Kerrek - I just tried it on [IdeOne](http://www.ideone.com/PKxtN) and it looks like the conversion operator takes precedence.

Comment: @Node: Sweet! Strangely, it seems to depend on the constness of the cast operator: [non-const](http://www.ideone.com/hUHi2), [const](http://www.ideone.com/XiwJQ). Also, note that there's a difference between `B b(a)` and `B b = a`!

Answer (score 1):

That's an implicit conversion operator. It basically allows an object of your class to be used in a context where a `size_t` is expected (calling that operator to do the conversion).

In order to use `unordered_set` you *need* to have some sort of hashign function. In this case, it's being disguised as `operator size_t`, which I don't really recommend because it's simply obfuscating the fact that it's a hash function. I would just go ahead and define a real hash function/functor and use that instead. It'll be more clear and future maintainers will thank you.

Comment: I regard(ed) as the best way as all things now can be included in the class itself. Can a real hash function/functor be included in the class itself? Would you please give more details about the _real_ hashing?